# Can we use one swf movie to show font in normal , bold and Italic in sifr 3?

Tags: sifr

Can we use one swf movie to show font in normal , **bold** and *Italic* on a html page in sifr 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just make sure to embed all variants and to properly set the `font-weight` and `font-style` properties.